# Permanent 301 Redirect Rule Not Working in .htaccess File for WordPress Website

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Google Search Console has a 500 server error for a WordPress Post preview URL, and I'm trying to create a 301 redirect for the URL, which I normally do with any Search Console permalink errors.

The URL format is:
https://example.com/file-name.php?preview_id=2097&preview_nonce=ef04840ae6&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true

I've tried numerous redirect attempts including:

Redirect 301 domain.com/file-name.php?preview_id=2097&preview_nonce=ef04840ae6&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true https://example.com

Redirect 301 "example.com/file-name.php?preview_id=2097&preview_nonce=ef04840ae6&_thumbnail_id=-1&preview=true" https://example.com

Comment: Have you also tried Redirection plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have tried the WordPress 'Redirection' plugin - same issue.